# Do we have an API to add tags to the documents we are uploading?

Tags: box-api

Like in CMIS we have properties and their corresponding values, I read somewhere we have tags in BOX. Do we have an API for adding Box tags, that can act as information about the file/folder that we are uploading/creating?

Answer (score 0):

Tags are available in the V1 API: http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923921/ApiFunction_add_to_tag

Comment: This is now deprecated.  Go to V2 Docs for tags

Answer (score 0):

Tags are also available in the V2 API:  http://developers.box.com/#files  or http://developers.box.com/#folders.   They are associated with files or folders, and are set with a PUT operation on the /files/ or /folders/ resource, as appropriate.